# How to implement a sortable column on associated record's count in ajax-datatables-rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datatables

Is there any way to do this? I can't implement the counter cache because the where clause is used when retrieving a count.

Comment: Don't know if this will help, but I've had pretty good success with Filterrific gem when sorting table. http://filterrific.clearcove.ca/pages/action_view_api.html#filterrific_sorting_link